# Problems while traversing and extracting the nodes of a tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion, data-structures

I have the following trees ([tree_1](https://pasteboard.co/IqIwzx.png), [tree_2](https://pasteboard.co/IqIwGb.png), [tree_3](https://pasteboard.co/IqIxcj.png)) stored in a dictionary ([dict_1](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PPj9fFcRq/), [dict_2](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pGnSZXnC3/), [dict_3](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2hr7bq2jc/)). **How can I recursively traverse all the paths of the tree, collecting all the nodes from the root to the last node of each branch?**

In other words, I would like to generate a list of all the possible sequences of nodes for all the branches of the trees (dicts). For example some possible branches for [dict_1](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PPj9fFcRq/) ([tree_1](https://pasteboard.co/IqIwzx.png))are:

```
[["FunctionDef", "try", "ExceptHandler", "Expr", "Call", "Attribute","Load"],
["FunctionDef", "try", "ExceptHandler", "Expr", "Call", "Attribute","save_dictionary"],
["FunctionDef", "try", "ExceptHandler", "Expr", "Call", "Attribute","Name", "self"],
..., 
["FunctionDef", "arguments", "arg", "self"]]
```

So far, from a previous question I tried to:

```
def foo(nested_dict, c = []):
   for i in ['left', 'op', 'right', 'func', 'value', 'args', 'ctx',
             'body', 'comparators', 'ops', 'test', 'orelse', 'targets', 'slice', 'n', 'id', '_type']:
      if i in nested_dict:
        if isinstance(nested_dict[i], list):
            for b in nested_dict[i]:
                yield from foo(b, c+[nested_dict['_type']])
        elif isinstance(nested_dict[i], dict): #simple check here
            yield from foo(nested_dict[i], c+[nested_dict['_type']])
        else:
            yield c+[nested_dict[i]]
```

and

```
def foo_2(nested_dict, c = []):
  targets = {'left', 'op', 'right', 'func', 'value', 'args', 'ctx', 'body',
             'comparators', 'ops', 'test', 'orelse', 'targets', 'slice', 'n',
             'id', 'slice', 'annotation', 'arg', 'elts', 's', '_type'}
  for a, b in nested_dict.items():
     if a in targets:
        if isinstance(b, dict):
           yield from foo_2(b, c+[a])
        elif isinstance(b, list):
           for i in b:
              yield from foo_2(i, c+[a])
        else:
            yield c+[b]
```

However, both of them don't work because I am getting the wrong sequences. I tried to modify the targets because I thought that this issue was related to the fact that a target can not be reached out. Nevertheless, I am getting either incomplete or incorrect paths, and in general it is still not working, any idea of how to generate one list per path given a tree?

Here's a minimal example, given this tree:

```
{'_type': 'Expr',
 'col_offset': 0,
 'lineno': 1,
 'value': {'_type': 'Call',
  'args': [{'_type': 'BinOp',
    'col_offset': 6,
    'left': {'_type': 'Num', 'col_offset': 6, 'lineno': 1, 'n': 1},
    'lineno': 1,
    'op': {'_type': 'Add'},
    'right': {'_type': 'Num', 'col_offset': 8, 'lineno': 1, 'n': 2}}],
  'col_offset': 0,
  'func': {'_type': 'Name',
   'col_offset': 0,
   'ctx': {'_type': 'Load'},
   'id': 'print',
   'lineno': 1},
  'keywords': [],
  'lineno': 1}}
```

The output should be:

```
[["Expr", "Call", "Name", "print"],
["Expr", "Call", "Name", "Load"],
["Expr", "Call", "Binop", "Num", "1"],
["Expr", "Call", "Binop", "add"],
["Expr", "Call", "Binop", "Num", "2"]]
```

Comment: I added a new short example @kabanus

Comment: Very, nice gave you hand.

Comment: links to `tree_1`, `tree_2`, `tree_3`, `dict_1`, `dict_2`, and `dict_3` have all rotted. SO encourages hosting code examples and image in your post instead of linking off-site resources for this reason.

Comment: they expired, let me upload again @user633183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first small fix for function 1 is to notice branches ending with a `dict` containing only `_type` and branches ending with a simpler object (`id` for example), are both handled with your `else`, but require two different things:

1. The first will be handled with a `dict` recursive call, and so will add the previous `_type` node.
2. The second one, will get to `else` in the previous node iteration, but only adds itself, meaning you forgot the "current" `_type` node. So the `else` becomes:

   ```
   elif i == '_type':
       #Got here recursively, previous node already added
       yield c+[nested_dict[i]]
   else:
       #Got here in the iteration of the "previous" node, so need to add it as well.
       yield c+[nested_dict['_type'],nested_dict[i]]
   ```

No you will get all your branches, but you also get all sub-branches 
(`['Expr'],['Expr','Call'],['Expr','Call','BinOp']...`). This means we are yielding at a wrong place somewhere! We are yielding `_type` nodes now even if they are not leaves. It's also clear that we always need `c` to have `_type` anyway. Second solution that pops to mind:

```
def foo(nested_dict, c = []):
    yielded = False
    c = c+[nested_dict['_type']] #Good place for try...except and validation check
    for i in ['left', 'op', 'right', 'func', 'value', 'args', 'ctx',
    'body', 'comparators', 'ops', 'test', 'orelse', 'targets', 'slice', 'n', 'id']:
        if i in nested_dict:
            yielded = True
            if isinstance(nested_dict[i], list):
                for b in nested_dict[i]:
                    yield from foo(b, c)
            elif isinstance(nested_dict[i], dict): #simple check here
                yield from foo(nested_dict[i], c)
            else:
                yield c+[nested_dict[i]]
    #`_type` is leaf
    if not yielded: yield c
```

Note I removed `_type` from the oeprations since there is no point in iterating it now. This way we can just use `else` in the loop. Function 2 is the same thing, so I leave you to fix it.

Comment: Running your large example I see you may be missing operations/keys whatever (`arg`, `handlers`...). If you had some rule how you get these that would be more robust.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Although the fix that you propose is fine it is missing to traverse some paths. For example, this [tree](https://pasteboard.co/IqQK46d.png) represented as this [dict](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/trgwpt4GGJ/). The output is [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WPc3NbNCtJ/), which is missing some paths. What can I do for those cases? I tried to add for example `name ` to the targets but it is still not working properly

Comment: @JDo Like I said, you are missing keys in your big list of keys `['left','right'...]` such as `arg` and `handlers`. Add them or those paths will be discarded (by your own design).

Comment: I tried to add them to the list and still having issues.. any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @JDo you'll have to be more specific - are the same paths stil missing? Did only a few more appear, but some are still missing? If the latter you probably just gave to figure out what keys you are missing from the list.

Comment: For example, from the attached tree, dict, and output in the comments, when I added `'name','arg'` to the list of keys. I am getting this sequences which are wrong: `['FunctionDef', 'Expr', 'Str']`. Also, in the tree I am not getting: `['FunctionDef', 'If', 'BoolOp', 'Call', 'Str', 'container'], ['FunctionDef', 'If', 'BoolOp', 'Call', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'If', 'BoolOp', 'Call', 'Name', 'ctx'], ['FunctionDef', 'If', 'BoolOp', 'Call', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'If', 'BoolOp', 'Call', 'Name', 'hasattr']`

Comment: BTW, I am generating the dicts from code with this [lib](https://github.com/YoloSwagTeam/ast2json)

Comment: @JDo Sorry, but you have to start debugging yourself. I can clearly see that "wrong" path in the `dict` you linked to at `x['body'][0]['_type']` (`Expr`) and `x['body'][0]['value']['_type']` (`Str`) - per your definitions so far, that is an acceptable path. You have to sit now and amend the code to what you want, not add requirements here - we can't handle all the edge cases.